# Updating MS Access Data Table from Closed CSV without Importing

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ms-access

I was wondering if there was a way (preferably VBA or Access SQL code) to update an MS Access data table from a closed CSV without importing the CSV?

I can only seem to update the data by importing the CSV first which I do not want to do.

Comment: What else have you tried (other than importing)?

Answer (score 0):

Link the CSV file. It will appear as a linked table.

Now, create your update query using this linked table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

I got around this by using VBA to run a saved import specification (requires manual import on first attempt):

```
    Sub test()

'open database

        Static acc As Access.Application
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim dbname As String
        dbname = "C:\Users\br93\Documents\Database1.accdb"
        Set acc = New Access.Application
        acc.Visible = True
        Set db = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbname, False, False)
        acc.OpenCurrentDatabase dbname

'run import spec

        acc.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Test2"

'close and save the workbook

        acc.DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll

        db.Close
        Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```